# SAPUI5 OData model with different metadata URI

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am using an OData model for a table, but the data is not loaded. The OData model is created by constructor in the following way:

```
new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/XMII/IlluminatorOData/QueryTemplate?QueryTemplate=testTemplate", {annotationURI: "/XMII/IlluminatorOData/$metadata"});
```

I cannot use the root URI of the OData service, because I need to specify a QueryTemplate.

After setting the model to the table, bindRows method is invoked with parameter "/Row".

```
table.bindRows("/Row")
```

The template for a column is a TextField.

```
template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value", "PROJECT")
```

The data is not shown and not even requested. Only metadata is fetched. What am I doing wrong with OData model? If I fetch the URI which was passed to the model with a get request, content is available.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the URL is right?

Shouldn't it be something like "/XMII/IlluminatorOData/?QueryTemplate=testTemplate"

The ODataModel needs to load the metadata in order to work, this means it fetches it from "[ServiceUrl]$metadata", which would be "/XMII/IlluminatorOData/QueryTemplate/$metadata" in your case. But you also use the metadata as annotation source - there you use a different URL, so I guess you first one is wrong...?

Comment: I know that it's not the root URI of the OData service. Therefore I set the right metadata URI, but maybe this is not the right way of doing this.

Comment: No, you set the annotation-URI, the metadata is loaded from the URL I wrote in my answer. Annotations can be part of the metadata but they do not have to be - look into your network-tab in the developer-tools of your browser and you will see what URLs are requested.

Comment: I searched the OData spec for a specific reference to the metadata-URL, there seems to be none, but all examples use [ServiceURL]/$metadata. The UI5 ODataModel does not support metadata at a different URL - it is hardcoded, see https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel.js#L167 (The same applies for the v1 ODataModel).